# Limit and offsets are not working for Facebook me/feed connecton

Tags: facebook-graph-api, pagination

I have found that if Graph Connection me/feed is used with limit and offset then its returning empty json array for most of limit and offset values.
For example:-

me/feed?limit=10&offset=0 is giving proper data

But me/feed?limit=10&offset=10 is returning empty json data array

Please help me :( thanks in advance....

** This behavior can be reproduced with the GRAPH API explorer tool too and I have got all the permissions possible using the GRAPH API explorer tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing similar experimentation on the graph api and I think that the the offset is with in the retrieved data set. This means that when you are retrieving only ten items and starting from 10th offset then zero items will be returned. However, if limit is greater than offset then some data would be returned.
See this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/388166594574941/) as well